# Converting an EditBox input into dots after a user inputs a single char?

Tags: android, android-edittext

1] 4 digit input boxes without input:

[image]

2] 4 digit input boxes with input :

[image]

As the user goes on entering 4-digit pin input box is turned into the dot, if the user wants to delete the last digit pressing back button user input gets deleted with dots again converting to the input box. If the user has middle input incorrect he can't convert dot into input box by touching it he has to traverse back deleting from right-to-left.

I see possible solution having [the custom widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) with setting views visible/gone based on user input detected via implementing [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). But does existing [EditText widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) in Android platform has any style configuration by making use of which I can code in XML to get above-mentioned UI change?

So far for the manual change, I have done following changes ( Code given for one input box this has been used to create group of 4 input boxes) :

XML layout for single input box :

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/pin_edit_box"
                    style="@style/pin_edittext_style"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:digits="0123456789"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="numberPassword" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/pin_input_dot"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minEms="3"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_green_dot"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Text change listener :

```
pin_edit_box.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
int length = editable.toString().length();
        if (length == 1) {
            pin_edit_box_this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pin_input_dot_this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        pin_edit_box_next.requestFocus();
        } else if (length == 0) {
// This part doesn't work as EditText is invisible at this time 
// dot image view is visible
            pin_edit_box_this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pin_input_dot_this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        pin_edit_box_this_previous.requestFocus();
        }
            }
        });
```

When trying to detect back or delete button event from

```
boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, 
                KeyEvent event) {
}
```

The event of keyboard `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL` never gets detected to make views visible/invisible after the back press. Official documentation says will not always work the soft-keyboard events may not always get delivered.

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting
>   text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will
>   generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in
>   fact sending such events is discouraged.

[More details here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Note: Screenshots above are taken from [BHIM application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.org.npci.upiapp&hl=en) which is for Indian money transactions.

Comment: AnimatedDrawable doesn't suite here?

Comment: I think it worth to check this out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this [PinView Library](https://github.com/ChaosLeong/PinView), it does almost the same as you want.

It's easy to use :

Add the `dependencies`

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.3.0'
}
```

Instead of `EditText` create a `PinView`

```
<com.chaos.view.PinView
    android:id="@+id/pinView"
    style="@style/PinWidget.PinView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Hint."
    android:inputType="text"
    android:padding="@dimen/common_padding"
    android:textColor="@color/text_colors"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    app:cursorColor="@color/line_selected"
    app:cursorWidth="2dp"
    app:itemCount="5"
    app:itemHeight="48dp"
    app:itemRadius="4dp"
    app:itemSpacing="0dp"
    app:itemWidth="36dp"
    app:lineColor="@color/line_colors"
    app:lineWidth="2dp"
    app:viewType="rectangle" />
```

You should see something like this 
[image]

Other workaround is to create your own `EditText` class and change it when user types

Comment: thanks for the response this is exactly what I want, but isn't there any way in EditBox widget? if not I may make use your answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/normal"
        android:hint=""
        android:maxLength="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint=""
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/normal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLength="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint=""
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/normal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLength="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint=""
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/normal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLength="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**@drawable/norma**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:height="1dp"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#0011ff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**drawable.filled**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:height="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00001eff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**ACTIVITY CODE**

```
    import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edt1, edt2, edt3, edt4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edt1 = findViewById(R.id.edt1);
        edt2 = findViewById(R.id.edt2);
        edt3 = findViewById(R.id.edt3);
        edt4 = findViewById(R.id.edt4);

        edt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt1.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    edt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
                    edt1.requestFocus();
                    edt1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.black));
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            edt1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
                        }
                    },500);
                } else {
                    edt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filled);
                    edt1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.red));

                    edt2.requestFocus();
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            edt1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                                    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                        }
                    },500);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });


        edt2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt2.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    edt2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
                    edt2.requestFocus();
                    edt2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.black));
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            edt2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
                        }
                    },500);
                } else {
                    edt2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filled);
                    edt3.requestFocus();
                    edt2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.red));
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            edt2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                                    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                        }
                    },500);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        edt3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt3.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    edt3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
                    edt3.requestFocus();
                    edt3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.black));
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            edt3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
                        }
                    },500);
                } else {
                    edt3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filled);
                    edt3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.red));
                    edt4.requestFocus();
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            edt3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                                    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                        }
                    },500);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });


        edt4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt4.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    edt4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
                    edt4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.black));
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            edt4.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );
                        }
                    },500);
                } else {
                    edt4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filled);
                    edt4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.red));
                    edt4.clearFocus();
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            edt4.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                                    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                        }
                    },500);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

**NORMAL**  [image]

**WHEN EDIT**  [image]

**FINAL** [image]

Comment: This is the manual way I can try thanks for the suggestion. +1

Comment: @pcj welcome let me know in case of any query happy codding

Comment: I have tried the manual way you said by your way it doesn't replace text input it sets background image keeping input text visible, I wanted to change the input text to red or green dot. Which seems not possible with your approach I tried something using ImageView which also doesn't work ( See updated question ) may end up using PinView Library suggested in other answer, Thanks.

Comment: tried manual approach it is failing to bring dot-like the image in edit boxes forefront I used PinView library thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your Edittext input type into textpassword, its will show char as dot char.

Comment: I don't want it that way, Thanks for response